# How to resolve an instance of a closed generic type from a type instance and use it?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, dependency-injection, autofac

Lets say you have a couple of open generic abstract classes:

```
public abstract class AbstractActionHandler<TInput>
{
    public abstract Task Action(TInput input);
}

public abstract class AbstractFunctionHandler<TInput, TOutput>
{
    public abstract Task<TOutput> Function(TInput input);
}
```

Then you have a couple of implementations:

```
public class IntActionClass : AbstractActionHandler<int>
{
    public Task Action(int input)
    {
        //do some work...
    }
}
public class StringActionClass : AbstractActionHandler<string>
{
    public Task Action(string input)
    {
        //do some work...
    }
}
public class IntFunctionClass : AbstractFunctionHandler<int, string>
{
    public Task<string> Function(int input)
    {
        //do some work...
    }
}
public class StringFunctionClass : AbstractFunctionHandler<string, bool>
{
    public Task<bool> Function(string input)
    {
        //do some work...
    }
}
```

Now you want to register all of the implementations in your assembly in your IoC container so that dependencies can be resolved:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
var openGenericTypes = new[]
{
    typeof(AbstractActionHandler<>),
    typeof(AbstractFunctionHandler<,>)
};

var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var implementationTypes = new List<Type>();

foreach (var openGenericType in openGenericTypes)
{
    var types = assembly.GetTypes()
        .Where(type => type.IsAssignableFrom(openGenericType))
        .Where(type => !type.IsAbstract);

    builder.RegisterTypes(types.ToArray())
        .AsClosedTypesOf(openGenericType)
        .InstancePerDependency();

    implementationTypes.AddRange(types);
}

var container = builder.Build();
```

Now you have a list of implementationTypes, and you want to iterate through the list and resolve an instance of each type as their closed generic type. This is where the problem occurs:

```
foreach (var type in implementationTypes)
{
    var handler = container.Resolve(type); 
    // handler is of type object but needs to be of its closed generic type
    // ie. AbstractAbstractHandler<int>

    if (type == typeof(AbstractActionHandler<>))
    {
        // This should be called for all classes closing AbstractActionHandler<>
        ConstructActionHandler<TInput>(handler); // calls AbstractActionHandler.Action
    }
    else if (type == typeof(AbstractFunctionHandler<,>))
    {
        // This should be called for all classes closing AbstractFunctionHandler<>
        ConstructFunctionHandler<TInput, TOutput>(handler); // calls AbstractFunctionHandler.Function
    }
}

public void ConstructActionHandler<TInput>(AbstractActionHandler<TInput> handler)
{
    var actionHandlerWrapperDelegate = new Func<TInput, Task>(async (input) =>
    {
        await actionHandler.Action(input);
    });
    // ....
}
```

So the first question is: how do i resolve an instance of a closed generic type from a type instance?

I thought about creating a generic wrapper class that can be instantiated with Activator.CreateInstance() and let the wrapper resolve the correct handler, but im not sure if that would be the correct approach.

Furthermore, lets say you want to have a list of handlers of different generic argument types:

```
// this would not be possible
var actionHandlers = new List<AbstractActionHandler<TInput>>();

// this would however be possible
var actionHandlers = new List<IActionHandler>();
var functionHandlers = new List<IFunctionHandler>();
```

And you want to connect them in some way by their type argument:

```
foreach (var actionHandler in actionHandlers)
{
    var actionHandlerTypeArgument = handler.GetType().GenericTypeArguments.First();
    var functionHandler = functionHandlers.Find(handler => 
            handler.GetType().GenericTypeArguments.First() == actionHandlerTypeArgument);

    var wrapper = new Func<TInput>(async input => 
    {
        var output = functionHandler.Function(input);
        actionHandler.Action(output);
    });
    // ...
}
```

How would i downcast an instance of IActionHandler or IFunctionHandler to its closed generic interface?

The solution to this question might be the same as the solution to the first question. I only separated them since the approach to the first problem might be the wrong way to go about it.

Any type of input would be highly appreciated!
If there is a better approach to this, i'd be glad to hear that too.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This form of unconstructed generic types (`typeof(AbstractActionHandler<>)`, `typeof(AbstractFunctionHandler<,>)`) is called a *generic type definition*. You can use reflection to determine whether or not a type has a specific generic type definition in one of its base classes. For instance,

```
    private static bool HasGenericBase(Type type, Type baseGenericTypeDefinition)
    {
        if (!baseGenericTypeDefinition.IsGenericTypeDefinition)
            throw new ArgumentException($"The specified type ({baseGenericTypeDefinition}) is not a generic type definition");
        while (type.BaseType != typeof(object))
        {
            type = type.BaseType;
            if (type.IsGenericTypeDefinition && type == baseGenericTypeDefinition)
            {
                return true;
            }
            if (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == baseGenericTypeDefinition)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

You can use it in your model like that:

```
        foreach (var type in implementationTypes)
        {
            var handler = container.Resolve(type);
            // handler is of type object but needs to be of its closed generic type
            // ie. AbstractAbstractHandler<int>

            if (HasGenericBase(type, typeof(AbstractActionHandler<>)))
            {
                // This should be called for all classes closing AbstractActionHandler<>
                ConstructActionHandler<TInput>(handler); // calls AbstractActionHandler.Action
            }
            else if (HasGenericBase(type, typeof(AbstractFunctionHandler<,>)))
            {
                // This should be called for all classes closing AbstractFunctionHandler<>
                ConstructFunctionHandler<TInput, TOutput>(handler); // calls AbstractFunctionHandler.Function
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you may want to avoid storing the list of implementations of your abstract types (that is what the container is for).

I'm imagining that at some point in your program, you want to access the implementation of `AbstractActionHandler<TInput>`, whatever that might be, and use it.

If you ask Autofac for the `AbstractiActionHandler<int>` or `AbstractActionHandler<string>`, it'll figure out which of your action implementations to use, and return it to you.

I've got an example here that sort of explains what I'm getting at:

```cs
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

    builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly)
        .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(AbstractActionHandler<>));

    builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly)
        .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(AbstractFunctionHandler<,>));

    var container = builder.Build();

    // At some point later...
    await InvokeActionHandler(container, 100);

    // or...
    await InvokeActionHandler(container, "something");
}

private static Task InvokeActionHandler<TInput>(IContainer container, TInput inputArg)
{
    var handler = container.Resolve<AbstractActionHandler<TInput>>();

    return handler.Action(inputArg);
}
```

You can use the same approach to get `AbstractionFunctionHandler<TInput, TOutput>`.

As for how to link them together, this gets a bit complicated if we don't want to change your base classes too much; one option might be to attach the output type of the function registration in [Metadata](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/metadata.html), and declare an interface that is only generically-typed to the function input.

Then you can determine the action type you need at runtime (in a wrapper type, for example) and resolve it.

Something like this:

```cs
class Program
{

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly)
            .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(AbstractActionHandler<>));

        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly)
            .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(AbstractFunctionHandler<,>))
            // Registering a second service here.
            .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(IDynamicFunctionHandler<>))
            // Capturing the output type argument (this is not robust if there are multiple inheritance levels).
            .WithMetadata("output", t => t.BaseType.GenericTypeArguments[1]);

        // Register an open-generic registration wrapper.
        builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(FuncActionCombo<>));

        var container = builder.Build();

        await InvokeActionFromFunctionResult(container, 100);
    }

    private static async Task InvokeActionFromFunctionResult<TInput>(IContainer container, TInput input)
    {
        // Resolve our combo class (that is only typed to the input).
        var funcHandler = container.Resolve<FuncActionCombo<TInput>>();

        await funcHandler.Invoke(input);
    }
}

public interface IDynamicFunctionHandler<TInput>
{
    Task<object> FunctionDynamic(TInput input);
}

public abstract class AbstractFunctionHandler<TInput, TOutput> : IDynamicFunctionHandler<TInput>
{
    public abstract Task<TOutput> Function(TInput input);

    // Just wrap the regular function.
    public async Task<object> FunctionDynamic(TInput input) => await Function(input);
}

public class FuncActionCombo<TInput>
{
    private readonly IDynamicFunctionHandler<TInput> _funcHandler;
    private readonly object _actionHandler;
    private readonly MethodInfo _actionInvokeMethod;

    public FuncActionCombo(IComponentContext context, Meta<IDynamicFunctionHandler<TInput>> handlerWithMeta)
    {
        _funcHandler = handlerWithMeta.Value;

        // Get the output type data we attached to the registration.
        var outputType = (Type) handlerWithMeta.Metadata["output"];

        // Create a closed type of the action handler from the output type.
        var closedActionHandler = typeof(AbstractActionHandler<>).MakeGenericType(outputType);

        // Resolve the implementation.
        _actionHandler = context.Resolve(closedActionHandler);

        // Get the method declaration.
        _actionInvokeMethod = closedActionHandler.GetMethod(nameof(AbstractActionHandler<object>.Action));
    }

    public async Task Invoke(TInput input)
    {
        var result = await _funcHandler.FunctionDynamic(input);

        // Invoke our dynamic Action.
        await (Task) _actionInvokeMethod.Invoke(_actionHandler, new[] { result });
    }
}
```

It's still not great, but anything else would probably require a more fundamental rethink of how you are approaching this.